# Xamarin Form ListView SelectedItem MVVM Binding Error XFC0009

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to Bind SelectedItem of ListView to ViewModel Proper using MVVM Archtecture but its giving

> Error XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "ItemSelected", or mismatching type between value and property.
>
> E:\Xamarin\CoffeeAppListView\CoffeeAppListView\CoffeeAppListView\Views\CoffeeEquipmentPage.xaml (line 23)

Code snippets are

XML:

```xml
<ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
              BackgroundColor="Transparent"
              ItemsSource="{Binding CoffeeGroups}"
              IsGroupingEnabled="True"
              GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"
              HasUnevenRows="true"
              SeparatorVisibility="Default"
              IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
              IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy,Mode=OneWay}"
              RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
              RefreshControlColor="DarkBlue"
              ItemSelected="{Binding SelectedCoffee, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

ViewModel:

```cs
public Coffee SelectedCoffee
{
    get => selectedCoffee;
    set
    {
        if(value!=null)
        {
            Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Selected", value.Name, "OK");
            previouslySeelcted = value;
            value = null;
        }
        selectedCoffee = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your whole Xaml page? It's possible that it could be an issue with te BindingContext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ItemSelected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.itemselected?view=xamarin-forms) is an event

[SelectedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.selecteditem?view=xamarin-forms) is a bindable property